# Music option in game

Tags: javascript, html, game-engine

I'm having problem on applying the sound in my html game. I want it that, when I push the "no music" button, the whole html pages including other linked pages with the option page have no music.

My current problem is, when i apply the music button on the option page, it only works on the option page but it doesn't work at the other pages such as the homepage. How to link the music option button so that it works with the other page?

Answer (score 0):

Lets see if I correctly understood your question...

One way to solve this problem would be to create an `gameOptions` object/array that you store as a cookie or in local storage and whenever you load a page you load the object and check the variables.  As far as I am aware these are the only reliable ways to persist data through your site on the front end.

so you might do...

```
function loadGameOptions(){
var gameOptions = {'music':false} ;
if(localStorage.getItem('gameOptions') == null)
    localStorage.setItem('gameOptions', gameOptions) ;
else 
    gameOptions = localStorage.getItem('gameOptions');
}
```

And then just use `gameOptions.music` to access the value.  You might stick this in your global JS file.  Cookies would probably be a better way to store the data.  Honestly I don't know that this is the best solution, just that given my understanding of your question it is a solution.

Another bad solution would be to create a create a http query string 
url?music=false`

Comment: I think we can assume OP does use HTML5 APIs (such as the mediaElements) so localStorage should be available on supported browsers.